# Having Trouble Formatting Grid Layout in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyserial

I am trying to make a basic GUI for a serial communications program I wrote. I am new to Tkinter but not new to python. I am having trouble getting everything to work out with the grid. I know this is a lot to ask, but can anyone advise me on how I should set up the coding to make a layout similar to what can be seen in the following picture? I have tried multiple times but it just will not work out.
Thanks in advance!

Here is a picture of my proposed layout

([Proposed Layout](http://www.flickr.com/photos/114542900@N03/11970754793/))

Here is the code I have now, I know it is not much. But it shows the general way I wanted to OOP.

import Tkinter

```
    class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):

        def __init__(self,parent):
            Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
            self.parent = parent
            self.initialize()

        def initialize(self):
            self.grid()

    if __name__ == "__main__":

        app = simpleapp_tk(None)
        app.title('my application')
        app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

What sort of problem are you having? This looks like a pretty straight-forward layout.

- the text box at the top is at row zero, column zero, and spans two columns
- "send File" is row one, column zero.
- "directory" is row one, column one
- "receive file" is row two, column zero
- "type file name" is row two, column one
- ...
- the bottom box is row seven, column zero, and spans two columns

Further, I'm guessing rows zero and seven need a weight of 1, and column 1 needs a weight of 1. Everything else gets the default weight of zero.

All of that translates quite easily to the various grid methods.